# Is it possible to create a Sametime plug in to schedule a multi-person chat to open automatically?

Tags: sametime

I want to create a plug in for Sametime so I can schedule a multi-person chat with a group of people to open, for example, everyday at 9:30 a.m.

- Is it possible to create such a plug in?
- Which APIs should I use?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Marcelo, did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet :( ...this is something I would like to do, but since it isn't urgent, I haven't did into this further.

Comment: http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/c2396071.pdf   
this will definately give you partial functionality but not complete :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the below links in your browser, on a system that has Sametime installed:

localhost:59449/stwebapi/listservices # list the API services

localhost:59449/stwebapi/chat?userid=user1@email.com|user2@email.com # open chat window with multiple users (user1 and user2)

Comment: Just tested it and it works, just like I needed (almost three years ago, ha!) Thanks.